# Why do I need to url encode =?

Tags: java, urlencode, url-encoding

I need to handle any given url that is passed to our library. So at first I did:

```
        URL url = new URL(filename);
        URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
        url = new URL(uri.toASCIIString());
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
```

For the url http://www.stackoverflow.com?title=Člen8FO this gave me a url of http://www.stackoverflow.com?title=%C4%8Clen8FO

And that returned a 403 when I made the request. So then I did:

```
        URL url = new URL(filename);
        URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), URLEncoder.encode(url.getQuery(), "UTF-8"), url.getRef());
        url = new URL(uri.toASCIIString());
```

Which gives me a url of http://www.stackoverflow.com?title%3D%C4%8Clen8FO

Why does it fail on an explicit =? I thought that was fully valid.

**Update:** This is so weird. The below code failed before, now it succeeds.

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.*;

public class UriIssue {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            openUriWithEncode("http://www.google.com/?q=\u010clen8FO");
            System.out.println("completed successfully");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("exception = " + ex);
        }

        try {
            openUriNoEncode("http://www.google.com/?q=\u010clen8FO");
            System.out.println("completed successfully");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("exception = " + ex);
        }

    }

    public static void openUriWithEncode(String fullUrl) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("openUriWithEncode(" + fullUrl + ")");
        URL url = new URL(fullUrl);
        String query = url.getQuery() != null ? URLEncoder.encode(url.getQuery(), "UTF-8") : null;
        URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), query, url.getRef());
        System.out.println("uri = " + uri.toASCIIString());
        url = new URL(uri.toASCIIString());
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
        stream.close();
    }

    public static void openUriNoEncode(String fullUrl) throws Exception {

        System.out.println("openUriNoEncode(" + fullUrl + ")");
        URL url = new URL(fullUrl);
        URI uri = new URI(url.getProtocol(), url.getUserInfo(), url.getHost(), url.getPort(), url.getPath(), url.getQuery(), url.getRef());
        System.out.println("uri = " + uri.toASCIIString());
        url = new URL(uri.toASCIIString());
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
        stream.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: What does url.getQuery() return in this example?

Comment: Both of your URL's worked for me, so check it again. However, URLEncoder.encode should be used for the values of parameters. Note that the URI call you make should URLEncode the query for you.

Answer (score 1):

You're encoding the entire query including the `=`, so of course the `=` is being encoded. You only need to encode the keys and the values, e.g.

```
URLEncoder.encode(key)+"="+URLEncoder.encode(value)
```

Comment: The problem I had was if I didn't encode the =, then it failed. It shouldn't, but it did. But now it is all working as expected. Very weird.

Comment: @DavidThielen I suggest you mis-identified your original problem.

Comment: could be. But that is the code I ran and I was getting that problem. I'm also thinking something may have been weird on my computer the first time.